# Wiki Markup Language

Tags: wiki, markup

Does the 2010 SharePoint wiki offer improved support for lightweight markup language? If so, where can I find the documentation?

For example, is there markup for bold text - external links - images ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not aware of changes to the wiki "language" used in SharePoint 2010.

The user interface has certainly improved. For example typing the `[[` characters will present a drop-down menu of available items to choose from (see this [post by Michal Pisarek](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/05/wiki-linking-in-sharepoint-2010/)).

If there are certain language features you are looking for, please update your post with more details.

Comment: I have added some examples. What I understand from your reply is that the only available wiki markup is for links, correct?

Comment: AFAIK, the only wiki "language" feature is still `[[` characters. I tried all possible wiki combinations and they are not available at SP wiki pages. So, markup is created mostly through the Ribbon GUI and is stored as html internally. I added description for the Christophe examples - on how to do it using GUI, but if the question is only about wiki "language", your answer is correct, so +1.

Answer (score 14):

Actually, almost all the SharePoint wiki markup is provided through the GUI (on the ribbon). So, there is no special SharePoint wiki syntax, except [[links]] syntax.

> where can I find the documentation?

When you create standard "Team Site", where is a page with tips on wiki markup, which mention `[[` command to create internal links. The url of this page is:

**/SitePages/How%20To%20Use%20This%20Library.aspx**

Now, about your samples:

> For example, is there markup for bold text

You can select text and press Ctrl-B, or appropriate ribbon button:

[image: bold]

> external links

[image: insert link]

> images

[image: insert image]

**Note**: If you'd like to create a wiki page markup programmatically, you will not need any wiki syntax, because the page contents is stored in html format, in appropriate document library's aspx-files.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed reply. I understand that wiki pages have a text editor menu, but my question is whether there are also inline commands (just like stackoverflow has both a menu and inline commands). Apparently the only one is [[.

Comment: Yep, all the formatting made through GUI is stored as HTML internally, so I don't think they have any hidden wiki syntax there except of `[[`. Anyway, I think this answer adds some information to the page, and may be useful "for future readers" :)

Comment: Lame.  They really need to add support for simple wiki markup.  The generated HTML is awful (especially if copying and pasting from Word or OneNote). -- It's nearly impossible (without lots of HTML editing) to get consistent styles as-is.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in other answers, SharePoint's wiki includes a ribbon which allows you to do most things.  The disadvantage to this is that this information is not encoded in the editable markup.  If you prefer your markup to be visible, read on.

**Wiki Links**

Placing double square brackets around content creates a link to a page of that name on the root of the site.  e.g. `[[Home]]` links to the page `/Home.aspx` and displays the link text `Home`.

Linking to content in sub folders can be done using forward slashes between directories in the path.  The text displayed will be the name of the page.  e.g. `[[subfolder/Demo]]` links to the page `/subfolder/Demo.aspx` and displays the link text `Demo`.

You can change the text displayed on a link by using the Pipe (`|`) character to separate the link's path and link text.  e.g. `[[subfolder/Demo|See a demo]]` links to the page `/subfolder/Demo.aspx` and displays the link text `See a demo`.

**SharePoint Links**

You can also link to other content within the same SharePoint site.  For example, if you have a list called Tasks you can link to it via `[[List:Tasks]]`.  Again you can use pipe characters to amend the displayed text.

To link to an item within that list, use the item's Title; e.g. `[[List:Tasks/Example Item]]`

**Character Escaping**

Certain characters/strings can be escaped by placing a backslash before them.  These characters are `[[`, `]]`, `\[[` and `\]]`.

**Third Party Options**

You can also install alternate wikis from third parties with their own markups.

- [SharePoint Wiki Plus](http://www.wikimatrix.org/show/SharePoint-Wiki-Plus) has a more comprehensive markup language in the style of Wikipedia.  However, this is **not** a free extension.

Comment: +1. But does this apply to 2010 or just 2013?

Comment: Both... - SP2010: http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/09/working-with-sharepoint-wikis/#AddNewPages   - SP2013: https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Create-and-edit-a-wiki-dc64f9c2-d1a2-44b5-ac59-b9d535551a32?CorrelationId=ddf7a7f4-0158-4f0d-a881-5642454f8949&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bm5